# python - Publish message to SNS with Lambda request body

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have an AWS Lambda that is triggered through API Gateway set up with the following code:

```
import json
import boto3

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    client = boto3.client('sns')

    response = client.publish(
        TargetArn='arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:264604750251:Billing_SubscriptionMessage_1',
        Message=json.dumps({'default': json.dumps(event['body'])}),
        MessageStructure='json'
    )
   
    return response
```

However, it seems that `event` does not have the `body` key.

I'm using this Lambda with AWS Gateway in order to serve as a webhook listener. I want to pass the webhook data to my SNS topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out I was using an AWS Gateway of type **HTTP**, while I needed one of type **REST**, which passes the request body by default.